# Non-restrictive vs Sentential Relative Clause

Tags: grammaticality, differences, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

**I love my father, who is a teacher.**

*"Who is a teacher"* is a non-defining or non-restrictive relative clause.

**He failed the test, which shocked everyone.**

*"Which shocked everyone"* is a sentential relative clause.

> (1) Is there any difference between a non-restrictive relative clause & a sentential relative clause?
>
> (2) Are both of these independent clauses?

Comment: You should only ask a single question. Note that your second example sentence can be interpreted as a nonrestrictive relative clause too. (It was the test that shocked everyone, not the fact that he failed it.) Also, *who is a teacher*, unless it's a question, is not a standalone sentence—so it cannot be an independent clause. (The same applies to the second example.)

Comment: They are both supplementary (non-restrictive) relative clauses. I don’t like the term 'sentential relative clause' partly because it wrongly suggests that the clause itself is a sentence, partly because the antecedent is (normally) also not a sentence. In "He lost his temper, which was quite embarrassing" the antecedent is a clause, not a sentence.